# Wrong character after seeding database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF code-first approach to seed my SQL Server database with data but my Polish characters get converted. I didn't find anything to fix this issue on the internet.

This is my `Seed` method:

```
protected override void Seed(DataAccess.DataBaseContext context)
{
    context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(
        new DepartmentModel { Name = "Obróbka ręczna" }
    );
}
```

And this is what I get in the database:

```
Obróbka rêczna
```

The 'ę' character gets converted somehow.

Here is my model:

```
public class DepartmentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What is the collation for the `Name` column in your DB?

Comment: check collation using this SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'Collation')

Comment: @AdamV Collation is set to: Polish_CI_AS

Comment: you should also specify charset in your EF's connection string in such cases.